# NSArray from backend search Jsons into NSUserDefaults or Core Data or elsewhere?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I have a simple NSArray of Jsons in my app. It is an internal cache for my backend searches. That is if a user searches for objects, that gets thrown into my NSArray and should be saved. That array can thus get large, several thousand entries.

I think Core Data, Sqlite etc. all seems overkill to just save that NSArray so it doesn't get lost when the user closes the App. Meanwhile, I understand it is a misuse to just dump this NSArray into NSUserDefaults each time it is updated. Or is it better to write it to a file each time the NSArray gets updated and load it when the in my appdelegate when the app starts?

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: I think Core Data is not overkill to save an array with thousands of entries.

Comment: thanks, Mundi, after reading further into it, yes, Core Data is actually the only thing that will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, I recommend Core Data as a solution for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use NSJSONSerialization to read from and write to a file.